# Why it isn't searching the date?

Tags: c#

So I have 2 files here named
payment20200223 and withdraw20200223 as I wanted to search the file and rename if date today is found I searched that I can use this command

```
string FolderPath = @"C:\For Rename";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);

var files = di.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
    .Where(s => s.Name.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) || 
                !s.Name.Contains("." + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")))
    .ToList();

var Currentfile1 = files[0].FullName;         
var Currentfile2 = files[1].FullName;

//Parsing files
var Newfile1 = Currentfile1.Substring(0, Currentfile1.Length - 3);
var Newfile2 = Currentfile2.Substring(0, Currentfile2.Length - 3);

// Append new date
Newfile1 = Newfile1 + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + ".txt";
Newfile2 = Newfile2 + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + ".txt";

//Rename
File.Move(Currentfile1, Newfile1);
File.Move(Currentfile2, Newfile2);
```

but I tried to put date yesterday and still renaming it. non-developer asking for help here.

> Actual Input ( This is a server log)<

Payment20200223 ( Todays Log )
withdraw20200223 (Todays Log )

> Actual Output

Payment20200223.1000 ( Renamed output with actual time)
withdraw20200223.1000 ( Renamed output with actual time)

> Actual Output (After Re-run with new log)

Payment20200223 (2nd log today by the server )
withdraw20200223 (2nd log today by the server )
Payment20200223.1000.1001 ( actual output after re run)
withdraw20200223.1000.1001 ( actual output after re run)

> Desired Output

Payment20200223.1001 
withdraw20200223.1001 
Payment20200223.1000 
withdraw20200223.1000

Comment: Where are you putting yesterday date in the code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I did not put yesterday in the code, I have a textfile named payment20200222 and Withdraw20200222 but it sill rename it? I tried tot this s that it is only today ***s.Name.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))***

Comment: Please show some sample input, actual output, and expected output. It's not clear what your question is here.

Comment: @RufusL Noted sir, please wait

Comment: @RufusL Done adding the outputs and inputs

Comment: Shouldn't that check be using && to indicate you want files with the date and without the time?

Comment: @juharr will try that

Comment: @juharr **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.** error whhen using && instead of ||.

Comment: @ErnestStacks That means that it didn't find any results.  You should check if `files` is empty before attempting to index into it.  Or just iterate over `files` and do the renaming to all the matches (if there are none it will just skip the renaming).

Comment: @juharr but it has 2 text files in the folder named : 
payment20200223 and withdraw20200223, Because when I am using || It can be found but the problem is on 2nd re-run it will continue to rename each of it.

Comment: Actually if you have a file with 20200223.1000 and you test if it matches the date of 20200223 but not the time of 1001 that's still going to match so you could change the  search patteern from "*.txt" to `$"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.txt"` so that you don't even need to do the filtering.

Comment: @juharr I tried to put ```var files = di.EnumerateFiles($"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.txt")```

should I remove this part? 

```.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
            || !s.Name.Contains("."+DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")))

``` if YES it didnt still find the text file tried to put && instead still the same.

sorry about this I am not real into this kind I just need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't even need to use filtering here.  Instead leverage the pattern matching to only find files with the date followed by ".txt".

```
var files = di.EnumerateFiles($"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.txt")
    .ToList();
```

Then just iterate over the results to do the renaming

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
    //Parsing files
    var newFile = file.FullName.Substring(0, file.FullName.Length - 3);

    // Append new date
    newFile = newFile1 + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + ".txt";

    //Rename
    File.Move(file.FullName, newFile);
}
```

Comment: Will try this immediately

Comment: I am almost there just last 1 step. I have 2 files why is only renaming the **Withdrawal20200223** but not the **payment20200223**

Comment: It should match both.  What do you get if you open a command prompt and type in `dir "C:\For Rename\*20200223.txt"`.  That should match the same files.

Comment: found the missing number and this is so AWESOME! Thank you so much! you save my life here sir!

Comment: can I ask something a little bit out of this thread? Is it possible to rename that text file even if it is running? What I mean is it is a continous logs is it possible to rename it? because this was successful eventually when I deploy it did not rename the text file in production ( because it is running logs ) but on my testing it success. Just a random question thanks if you answer

Comment: @ErnestStacks According to the documentation for [`File.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8) if you attempt to move a file that is in use it will copy the file to the new name, but will not delete the original file, meaning you'd end up with two files.  Then if you attempted to rename it again since the file you want to rename it to exists it will fail.  Also if there's some other process that's creating these files it's hard to say what it will do if you rename a file out from under it.

Comment: I know this been to long and this is actually working on my end ( local ) but when I tried to put ( debug folder ) in the server that I will implement it why it isn't renaming. Note: I already arrange the correct path of the folder. Question: is there a extension that I need to install first or something it is a window server 2008 R2

Comment: @ErnestStacks I would recommend opening a new question and adding as much detail as you can about how you are using the code on that server.

Comment: already made a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540447/how-can-we-catch-an-error-in-c-sharp-on-the-server?noredirect=1#comment107111431_60540447)