# How can we catch an error in c# on the server

Tags: c#

So I have here a working code in my local machine.

What does is do is it will rename today's textfile.

> Path

**E:\Rename**

> Textfiles:

**WithdrawalConfirm20200305.txt**

**paymentpagecalls20200223.txt**

> Output:

**WithdrawalConfirm20200305.1400.txt**

**paymentpagecalls20200223.1400.txt**

where .XXXX is the time you run the program.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

            string dateandtimevar = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm");

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string FolderPath = @"E:\Rename";
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);

                var files = di.EnumerateFiles($"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.txt")
                .ToList();



                foreach (var file in files)
                {

                    //Parsing files
                    var newFile = file.FullName.Substring(0, file.FullName.Length - 3);


                    // Append new date
                    newFile = newFile + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + ".txt";

                    //Rename
                    File.Move(file.FullName, newFile);
```

Now my problem is when deploying to `win 2008 R2 server` it doesn't show any errors but it won't rename the text file like it does on my local machine. What could be wrong ?

I already checked the file path and the file exist on the server.

Comment: Did you check, if `files` contains items? -- What if there are only "older" files than from "today" `di.EnumerateFiles($"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.txt")`?

Comment: Yes I already check it as well but "today" is existing, I tried to copy a specific "today

Comment: The title asks how to catch the error, but the body of the question suggests that you want to know what the error is. Which is it?

Comment: Also, `file.FullName.Substring(0, file.FullName.Length - 3)` would still include the dot, so later with `+ ".txt"` the filename would have double dots. But that shouldn't be _the_ problem...

Comment: In windows you cannot rename a file if it is being used by a application.  So you must still have the file opened.

Comment: Yes I already check it as well but "today" is existing, I tried to copy a specific "today" file to a different folder but still the same and yes I re-build a new path as well.

Comment: @jdweng yes thats true in that case I tried to copy a file and transfer it to a different folder then re-build a the to update the file path but still the same

Comment: @Corak yes it will include the '.' to have a separtor between the date of the file and the time when it was edited. But I think it shouldnt be the problem because it was working totally fine here in my local machine.

Comment: The copy must still be open or used by an application.  I would not rename instead just save as new name in new folder.

Comment: @jdweng I tried to move to a different folder and to a different drive update the filepath in code and make sure notepad is not in the processlist still the same result. I am not sure why is not taking effect in this server but in my localmachine it works flawlessly.

Comment: Have you checked permissions and the relative/absolute path from your server to the folder?

Comment: Of course it would be best to debug on the server where it happens, but maybe writing debug-logs will be sufficient to track down the problem. First thing would be to log `files.Count`, then in the foreach, maybe the `file.FullName`, then the `newFile` (before the MessageBox), then again the `newFile` after appending the time. -- But since (as you say) "nothing happens", not even the MessageBox should show up, which let's me come back to my suspicion, that `files` is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't `File.Move` throw exceptions if there are any problems with still opened files or access rights or anything like that?

Comment: @AsheraH will check on that

Comment: @Corak yes you're correct with ```File.Move``` actually I tried not to put file with 'today' and with the existing it pops out an error.

Comment: @corak kindly ignore the message box as I am just trying to debug, my bad. Code is now updated in my post

Comment: Looks like a credential issue.  What happens if you try same using a File Explorer?

Comment: @jdweng Ill try and will update you, but is there will be credential issue if I use administrator account?

Comment: Possible.  Admin requires an admin on both local and remote machine.  When doing a copy from a command line instruction admins need to use the question mark to have access on remote machine.  You  can run Visual Studio as admin by creating a shortcut to VS and then right click shortcut and select run as admin.

Comment: @jdweng Still the same result. Been trying to debug it whole day now

Comment: Explain?  VS in admin mode, Windows Explorer?

Comment: @jdweng when I right click the shortcut and select run as admin in shortcut in VS, It will run the program like it use to be but the 2 files aren't renamed. Same in Windows explorer. It just run the normal way.

Comment: Can you rename with file explorer?  If you close vs and then reopen can you rename in c#.  Need to find out if it is a credential issue or just the fact the file is being used by another process.

Comment: @jdweng ill try it now .

Comment: Everyone I now found the issue it is all because of the extension because I am running and testing through all this time with '.txt' file but the actual file that I need to be renamed is '.log' it is now working thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the file extension of the file and make sure if it is `.txt` if not change it in your desired extension.

For example:

```
var files = di.EnumerateFiles($"*{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}.log")
```

```
newFile = newFile + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + ".log";
```